# How to have 100% coverage on branching python versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, code-coverage, gtk3

IN some code I am porting from Python 2 to 3 but which still needs to run on both, I have something like that:

```
if six.PY2:
    _text = widget.get_text().strip().decode('utf-8')
else:
    _text = widget.get_text().strip()
```

Because GTK-3 `widget.get_text()` returns bytes in Python 2 and unicode in Python 3. This is a PITA since the method I am passing `_text` to needs unicode. Thus, in Python 2 I must decode whatever data I get.

I have unit tests that mock `widget.get_text` but clearly, those run under one and only one version of Python. I could add a `pragma: no test` to the Python 2 branch but that feel like a cheat.

So, questions:

- How do I get 100% test coverage with the above *without pragma.*.
- How can I refactor this code so that I do not have the branch at all?

Answer (score 3):

Why not measure coverage under both versions, then combine the data and look for 100% in the combined results?

For example:

```
$ python2 -m coverage run --parallel run_the_tests.py
$ python3 -m coverage run --parallel run_the_tests.py
$ python3 -m coverage combine
$ python3 -m coverage html
```

Comment: That is … No idea you could do that! Could you kindly point me to the documentation as to how to do this? Thank you.